# location of android or android.bat

Tags: ant

I installed cygwin, ant, android ndk and android sdk.  I am following the instructions in slyvain's book "android ndk".  I am trying to do the following step:

Create Ant build file and all related configuration files automatically using android
command (android.bat on Windows). These files describe how to compile and
package an Android application:
android update project –p .

I get a message that android: `command not found.`

not sure why this wasn't installed or, not in the path.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME\tools`.

`$ANDROID_SDK_HOME` is the directory where you've installed Android SDK.

Also, remember to run `SDK Manager` first to fetch at least one Android build target.

Comment: funny.  went into windows and added the environment variable.  see it if i echo the path.  but, it still won't run.  i changed directories, in cygwin, to $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\tools  and tried to run android.bat  not found.  do an ls -al  it is there & executable.

Comment: only runs if i go into the $ANDROID_SDK_HOME and run ./android.bat